# Which conditions lead to a new instance of PropertyInfo being returned rather than a cached value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

When can I expect two references to `PropertyInfo` that represent the same property to *not* be the same instance?

E.g. If I get the `PropertyInfo` for a given class's property twice, I am typically returned the same instance both times:

```
var propertyOne = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(nameof(Foo.Bar));
var propertyTwo = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(nameof(Foo.Bar));
Console.WriteLine(propertyOne == propertyTwo); // Writes "True"
```

It is my understanding that this is not *guaranteed*, but under the hood .NET is caching the instance of `PropertyInfo` and returning it again on the second call to `GetProperty(...)`.

I have hit a scenario (when debugging in VS), where two property instances representing the same property on the same concrete class ended up not being equal (according to `Equals(...)`). I was able to check the details of the objects and could see that they had the same property name and type, and the same reflected type property etc., but were separate instances. In my case the instances of `PropertyInfo` are actually obtained from the body of a `LambdaExpression`. After hitting this during debugging, I have been completely unable to reproduce it, and always end up with the same instance of `PropertyInfo` no matter how I try to obtain it. I can find no trace of it occuring in our logs either. I expect I will switch the way I am comparing the instances to not rely on reference equality, but am just curious as to how it might occur or could be reproduced.

Under what conditions can it occur that different instance of `PropertyInfo` are returned?

Comment: I guess you should look into all recompile and continue scenarios (either debugging or ASP.Net partial updates on save of ASPX) and see if that can be confirmed/turned into answer...

Comment: Having look through the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs,bb264a178df104bc), it appears to me as the cache is never cleared. My guess is not guaranteed because you can get the same type from different app-domains where the cache has a separate state.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yep, I can reproduce it my modifying a source file and saving, thereby triggering a hot reload, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, interesting question. Lets see how far I can get from reading the source code.

Starting with an expression;

```cs
Expression<Func<C,bool>> expr = c => c.X;
```

C# compiles this to IL;

```
        IL_0001: ldtoken method instance bool C::get_X()
        IL_001c: call class [System.Runtime]System.Reflection.MethodBase [System.Runtime]System.Reflection.MethodBase::GetMethodFromHandle(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.RuntimeMethodHandle)
        IL_0021: castclass [System.Runtime]System.Reflection.MethodInfo
        IL_0026: call class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Property(class [System.Linq.Expressions]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, class [System.Runtime]System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
```

In other words calling `Expression.Property(..., MethodInfo)` with the `MethodInfo` representing the getter of the property, to build the `LambdaExpression` at runtime.

This `Property` [method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9e5d843c96634b619a22d318594a90dbd463802f/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/MemberExpression.cs#L300) then searches `mi.DeclaringType.GetProperties()` for a static / instance property with the same get / set method. With a slight complication if `mi.DeclaringType.IsInterface`;

```
// If the type is an interface then the handle for the method got by the compiler will not be the
// same as that returned by reflection.
// Check for this condition and try and get the method from reflection.
```

So not all `MethodInfo`s are `.Equal()`? Which sounds like a strange workaround, but maybe that could explain the difference you are seeing? Do you ever build a `LambdaExpression` based on an interface rather than a concrete type?

Comment: My case definitely uses the same concrete types. Both instance of `PropertyInfo` have the same `ReflectedType`, `PropertyType` and `DeclaringType`. They also have the same `MetadataToken` and `Module` which I believe confirms that they are representing the same property.